# Issues with paging through failure and rejection events returned by mailgun's api

Tags: php, mailgun

So, I've developed the following code:

```
const MAILGUN_API_MAX_LIMIT = 300; //max in documentation
$mgClient = new Mailgun\Mailgun("<mailgun_key>");
$domain = "<my_domain>";
$resultItems = array();

try {
    $result = null;
    $endTime_Epoch = time();
    $startTime_Epoch = $endTime_Epoch - 1440000; //400 hours
    $queryParams = array(
        'begin'        => $endTime_Epoch,
        'end'          => $startTime_Epoch,
        'limit'        => MAILGUN_API_MAX_LIMIT,
        'ascending'    => 'no',
        'event'        => 'rejected OR failed',
    );
    $request_url = "$domain/events";
    do {
        $result = $mgClient->get($request_url, $queryParams);
        if(!$result->http_response_body) {
            /*...*/
        } else if($result->http_response_code != 200) {
           /*...*/
        } else {

            $resultItems[] = $result->http_response_body->items;
            if(count($result->http_response_body->items) == MAILGUN_API_MAX_LIMIT) {
                $request_url = $result->http_repsonse_body->paging->next;
            }
        }
    } while($result && $result->http_response_body && count($result->http_response_body->items) == MAILGUN_API_MAX_LIMIT);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage()
}
```

But I'm having trouble getting it to page through the next set of requests if the limit ever gets hit (it probably won't, but it'd be bad in the event that something happened that made it happen).

I've tried reading mailgun's api doc, but i cannot, for the life of me, figure out what it is talking about with this:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient = new Mailgun('YOUR_API_KEY');
$domain = 'YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME';

$nextPage = 'W3siYSI6IGZhbHNlLC';

# Make the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->get("$domain/events/$nextPage");
```

But i can't figure out what that $nextPage is supposed to be. I've tried peeling off the start of the paging->next so it just ends up being $domain/events/, but that doesn't seem to be paging though it. I'm not really sure what to do here, or even what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit later than you would've hoped, but I've also been doing some stuff with the Mailgun and PHP lately.

So `$nextPage` is a value provided ***after*** your first API requests, so you don't need it at the start. Simply make your normal request like so

```
$result = $mailgun->get("$domain/events", $queryString);

// then we can get our 'Next Page' uri provided by the request
$nextURI = $result->http_response_body->paging->next;

// now we can use this to grab our next page of results
$secondPageResults = $mailgun->get($nextURI, $queryString);
```

Once thing worth noting though, is that Mailgun seems to **always** provide a 'next' link even when you've got all the results you want.

In my project I collected all results using a while loop after getting my initial records:

```
$hasNext = count($items) >= $queryLimit;

while($hasNext) {
    $nextResult = $mailgun->get($lastResult->http_response_body->paging->next, $queryString);
    $nextItems = $nextResult->http_response_body->items;
    $items = array_merge($items, $nextItems);

    $hasNext = count($nextItems) >= $queryLimit;
    $lastResult = $nextResult;
}
```

Hope this helps!